# Remove localhost:4200/xxx from router link

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular7-router

I want to redirect to another link using router link in angular 7 but localhost:4200/dashboard is getting appended to the link to which I want to redirect.

```
 <a  [routerLink]="https://google.com">Google</a>
```

When I click on Google, It should redirect to https://google.com but 
localhost:4200/dashboard/https://google.com is being called.

Comment: if you are going to redirect to an external link then use `href="https://google.com"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`routerLink` is for internal routing of Angular. If you want to navigate to an external URL, just use `href` with `a` tag:

```
<a  href="https://google.com">Google</a>
```

RouterLink: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Answer (score 0):

As the name `routerLink` implies it is meant for internal urls which are defined in your app routes. Please use this url to see how you can implement a custom one.

https://medium.com/@adrianfaciu/using-the-angular-router-to-navigate-to-external-links-15cc585b7b88

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-external-links